# Levy's characterisation of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

Is there a way to break the proof of the multidimensional characterisation of BM down to the one-dimensional case?

If we have $[M^{(i)},M^{(j)}]= \delta_{ij}t$ then each $M^{(i)}$ is already a BM and has vanishing cross-brackets with the other ones. How can I quickly obtain their independence?

Comment: So you are trying to conclude independence from their cross variation being zero?

Comment: I mean they are also Brownian motions.